# Cause of error in RcppExport

Tags: c++, rstudio, rcpp, armadillo

In a .cpp file that I'm editing in RStudio, the following code

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat mkGramMatrix (mat X, int n, double (*kernel) (mat, mat, double), double k_param=0){
  double (*func_kernel) (mat, mat, double);
  func_kernel = kernel;

  mat K(n, n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
      K(i, j) = func_kernel(X.row(i), X.row(j), k_param);
    }
  }
  return K;
}
```

produces the following error when I try to source inside RStudio:

```
KFDA_Rcpp.cpp:138:63: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_32_mkGramMatrix(SEXP XSEXP, SEXP nSEXP, SEXP double)SEXP, SEXP k_paramSEXP) {
                                                                       ^
KFDA_Rcpp.cpp:138:70: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_32_mkGramMatrix(SEXP XSEXP, SEXP nSEXP, SEXP double)SEXP, SEXP k_paramSEXP) {
                                                                              ^
                                                                              ;
KFDA_Rcpp.cpp:138:74: error: expected unqualified-id
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_32_mkGramMatrix(SEXP XSEXP, SEXP nSEXP, SEXP double)SEXP, SEXP k_paramSEXP) {
                                                                                  ^
3 errors generated.
```

Why is it placing a right parenthesis in

```
SEXP double)SEXP
```

when I believe I am using the function pointer correctly? I have successfully compiled and used other RcppArmadillo functions without problem but this is the first function I'm making that utilizes a function pointer so I can specify the kernel at the time I call this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a function pointer in the interface as it is not a type that maps to `SEXP`.

We can only call functions from R that map to the `.Call()` interface which requires `SEXP` arguments --- so we can use types for which we have mappers to and from `SEXP`.

The easy way out here is to use `Rcpp::XPtr`. It provides an 'external pointer interface' through which you can pass your kernel function. Inside the `mkGramMatrix()` function you can then dereference the `XPtr` to the functions you want to call. There are several posts here and on the Rcpp Gallery to get you started.  It is a *great* mechanism: hang in there and read up on it.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, being new to Rcpp I didn't know about XPtr. It sounds like that will be able to solve my problem in a straightforward manner. I'll post the working code once I complete it. And thank you for helping provide these awesome libraries in R, they are invaluable!